# Reverse decryption algorithm using binary operations

Tags: javascript, algorithm, encryption

I have a decryption algorithm where `x` is an 8 bit int:

```
function decrypt(x){
    return move(x, 2) ^ (move(x, 1) & move(x, 3));
}

function move(x, n) {
  return ((x >> (8 - n)) & 255) | ((x << n) & 255);
};
```

I would like to reverse the operation and find the encrypt function.

Comment: The `&` (bitwise AND)  operator has the problem that it removes information, so the function cannot be a permutation over all possible byte values. The `leftShift` isn't really a shift, it is usually called a `rotate` function, as it reintroduces bits on the right hand side. As a hint: just iterate over all 256 values and create a table.

Comment: From an editorial perspective: always make your title as specific as possible. Always include a tag for the language. Thinks like adding lots of exclamation marks are considered childish and make it less likely you get a good response.

Comment: What about a full table of all possible values for x and the encription? Would take 256 bytes and would make a lightning fast encoder.

Comment: @MrSmith42: As has been stated there is no way to reverse the function because it's not a permutation.

Comment: @President James K. Polk: Maybe only a subset of 0...255 is valid as input (8 bit input does not necessarily mean that all 8 bit values are possible). For a subset there could be an bijection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, because `decrypt` is not a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection), i.e. it is not invertable.

Take for example these numbers:

```
85, 91, 107, 109, 170, 173, 181, 182, 214, 218
```

If you pass *any* of these numbers to `decrypt`, the returned value will be 255. So if you are given 255, what would the hypothetical `encrypt` have to return? The fact is, that 255 does not have enough information to tell you where it came from.

This is just one counter example. There are other groups of numbers with the same `decrypt` output.